# A binomial convolution of Catalan numbers vs "utterly odd numbers"

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, elementary-proofs

An integer is called **utterly odd** if the terminal string of $1$’s in its binary representation has odd length. A number $2^{k+1}m+(2^k-1)$ where $m\geq0$ (every non-negative integer has this form) is utterly odd iff $k$ is odd.  The first few utterly odd positive numbers $1,5,7,9,13,17,21,23,25,29,31,\dots$ are listed on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A079523).

> **QUESTION.** Let $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ be the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). Is this true?
> $$a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kC_k\equiv0\mod 2 \qquad \text{iff} \qquad \text{$n$ is an utterly odd number}.$$

This is supported experimentally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$C_k$ is odd iff $k=2^s-1$, $s=0,1,\ldots$. $\binom{n}{2^s-1}$ is odd iff $s$ terminal binary digits of $n$ are 1's (by [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem)). Thus the result.